# Adobe AEM with IText PDF 7.1.x , java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Tags: maven, adobe, aem, itext7

I am using **IText PDF(7.1.x)** in **AEM 6.5**. I have added IText7 dependency to AEM as a sub project in AEM main project. The code is building successfully, but I am getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.itextpdf.io.font.FontRegisterProvider.<clinit>(FontRegisterProvider.java:68)
    at com.itextpdf.io.font.FontProgramFactory.<clinit>(FontProgramFactory.java:67)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory.createFont(PdfFontFactory.java:234)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory.createFont(PdfFontFactory.java:220)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory.createFont(PdfFontFactory.java:162)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory.createFont(PdfFontFactory.java:93)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.getDefaultProperty(RootElement.java:178)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.getDefaultProperty(Document.java:342)
    ............
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory not found by com.pdfgen
```

Please find the POM file of the sub project below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.pdfgen.itexttest</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfgen_itexttest</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>pdfgen_itexttest.itext</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Pdfgen IText POC</name>
    <description>IText bundle for POC/description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeArtifactIds>kernel,layout,bcprov-jdk15on,slf4j-api,slf4j-simple</includeArtifactIds>
                            <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bnd-process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bnd-process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <bnd><![CDATA[
Bundle-Category: ITextHtml2pdf
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.pdfgen
Import-Package: javax.annotation;version=0.0.0,
                !sun.*,
                org.slf4j,
                org.bouncycastle.asn1,
                *
Include-Resource: target/dependency/slf4j-api.jar,
                  target/dependency/slf4j-simple.jar
Bundle-ClassPath: .,slf4j-api
Export-Package: com.itextpdf.*
          ]]></bnd>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.apache.sling.caconfig.bnd-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                <artifactId>bnd-baseline-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissing>false</failOnMissing>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>baseline</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>baseline</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>io</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have tried a piece of PDF generation code which is working perfectly outside AEM but the I am getting the above error in AEM.

Answer (score 0):

The slf4j-api package is available on AEM - there is no need to import it. In fact importing it on your own might be the cause for your problem. Please try again without importing it - and make sure your dependency definition has a version set for slf4j that matches your AEM installation.

Apart from that I would suggest you switch to maven plugins like
filevault-package-maven-plugin to embed external dependencies.